# How do i find the Javascript code that makes a backend ajax call to get the data

Tags: web-scraping

I am looking at this webpage.
https://www.medtronic.com/covidien/en-us/products.html

I am trying to watch the xhr calls this webpage makes when we click on the product's description page like Ablation Systems or acute extracorporeal therapy solutions etc.

But when i launch the developer tools and look at the network call's that is being done I don't see anything.

When i launch the developer tools and inspect the network traffic after visiting https://www.medtronic.com/covidien/en-us/products/ablation-systems/emprint-sx-ablation-system.html  and by clicking
Order Information Button
I don't see how the table data gets created.

Is there a way from me to intercept the calls so I can download the data ?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about Chrome that's the way to do it. Just to be sure, open the network tab in developer tools before reloading the page and watch the events listed there while interacting with the page. If nothing shows up there's something wrong

Comment: are you sure it sends it as XHR? Maybe it sends it as normal request. OR maybe it has all data in HTML and it doesn't have to use XHR. Eventually it may use `websockets` for this. But I have no idea which data you try to get. Maybe better show on screenshots what you try to get.

Comment: you could show code which you use to get data, and you could add tag with language which you use in code.